# How to access a specific google drive account through a multi-user app?

Tags: c#, google-api

As the title says, How to handle a specific google drive account using the Google APIs located in an application that can be installed in multiple machines.

Cordially.

Comment: `As the title says, How to handle a specific google drive account using the Google APIs` it seems you know that you need use a Google API, what specific issue are you having, I am not seeing one.

Comment: i can access my current google account and the other user when he use my app he can access his account !
i simply want that the other user to access my google account through my app.

Comment: Ok, what specific issue are you having, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2, Google.Apis.Drive.v3 to manage some files inside a google drive account (i'll add my code in the answer below)
but as i said this code is to manage the current account (that refer to current user) !

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code using Google drive api and authentication :

```
private void btnAffFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> ListFiles = Manip_GDrive.GetListElem("",1000);
        for (int i=0; i < ListFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            RTBFiles.Text = RTBFiles.Text + "\nPage N° : " + (int)(i+1);
            if (ListFiles[i] != null && ListFiles[i].Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in ListFiles[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Name : " + file.Name + " // File Id : " + file.Id);
                    RTBFiles.Text = RTBFiles.Text + "\nFile Name : " + file.Name + " // File Id : " + file.Id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    static string ApplicationName = "my-project";

    public static List<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> GetListElem(string parentFolderId, int pageSize)
    {
        List<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> listAllElem = new List<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>>();
        try
        {
            if (InternetCnxState() == true)
            {
                DriveService service = Manip_GDrive.UserCredentialService("client_id.json");
                string pageToken = null;
                do //loop for all pages 
                {
                    var listRequest = service.Files.List();
                    if (parentFolderId != "") { listRequest.Q = "'" + parentFolderId + "' in parents"; }
                    listRequest.Spaces = "drive";
                    listRequest.PageSize = pageSize;
                    listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
                    listRequest.PageToken = pageToken;
                    var result = listRequest.Execute();
                    listAllElem.Add(result.Files);
                    pageToken = result.NextPageToken;
                } while (pageToken != null);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pas de connexion internet! \nVeuillez vérifier votre connexion internet avant de réessayer", "Hmidi Amine", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreure s'est produite! \nCode d'erreur : " + e.Message, "Hmidi Amine", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return listAllElem;
    }

    public static DriveService UserCredentialService(string streamJsonPath)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(streamJsonPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        return service;
    }
```